# splitting one column into several

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

First time poster here, so please forgive mishaps.

I have a query in sql that for the sake of simplicity returns duration, business duration and impacted service. The problem lies in the fact that if its impacted service, sometimes it has more than one value in the row. For example it can be 'crm, payrol and scheduling'. See below.

duration    business duration   impacted service
60                  40               crm
100                 95             payroll
70                  70             scheduling
50                  45    crm,scheduling, scheduling

What I want is an individual row for each of the values inside that one. Like so:

```
duration    business duration   impacted service
60                 40                  crm
50                 45                  crm
100                95                payroll
50                 45                payroll
70                 70               scheduling
50                 45               scheduling
```

How would you go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: The absolute best way to deal with this is to stop cramming multiple values in a single cell. This violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of anguish. To split this data requires some sort of a string splitter. Here are several good examples. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a split function.  Google "SQL Server split function" on the web.  Then you will have a split function.

You can then do this with `outer apply`:

```
select t.duration, t.business_duration, s.impacted_service
from t outer apply
     (dbo.split(t.impacted_service)) s(impacted_service);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
Declare @YourTable table (duration int,[business duration] int,[impacted service] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(60 ,40,'crm'),
(100,95,'payroll'),
(70 ,70,'scheduling'),
(50 ,45,'crm,payroll, scheduling')

Select Distinct 
       A.duration
      ,A.[business duration]
     ,[impacted service] = B.Key_Value
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.[impacted service],',')) B
```

Returns

```
duration    business duration   impacted service
50          45                  crm
50          45                  payroll
50          45                  scheduling
60          40                  crm
70          70                  scheduling
100         95                  payroll
```

The Parsing UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

    Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
    As
    Begin
       Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
       Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
       Return 
    End
```

Comment: This is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! This also works well, however, because I oversimplified the problem this wont work too well for me. But I have stored it in my stash of useful things. Thanks a lot!!